Linux, unresponsive key: keycode 248 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol) on xev
The "windows" key on my laptop stopped to work inexplicably.
When testing it using xev I get the following outputs:
KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x1000001,
    root 0x49f, subw 0x0, time 55638, (860,371), root:(960,540),
    state 0x10, keycode 248 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x1000001,
    root 0x49f, subw 0x0, time 55638, (860,371), root:(960,540),
    state 0x10, keycode 248 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

Thus, I assume that the issue might be software related. However, the key is unresponsive on Windows too (I have a dual boot).
A post on Reddit suggest that it could be solved using bind or Dconf without providing any precision. How would that be done?
Precisions

This is already the second time I have the issue. The first time it resolved itself after a while. I have no clue why nor how.

I recently updated to Ubuntu 24.04.

evtest shows the following events on keypress:


Event: time 1733389721.274977, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 4f
Event: time 1733389721.274977, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 240 (KEY_UNKNOWN), value 1
Event: time 1733389721.274977, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1733389721.274986, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 240 (KEY_UNKNOWN), value 0
Event: time 1733389721.274986, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------


It turned out to be a feature of my laptop: pressing the FN key along with the home key deactivate the home key. If your keyboard have a little lock on the corner of the home key it might be your case.
